# browser-sync does not handle most events in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack, browser-sync

For testing webapplications, I love to use browser-sync to simultaneously check the webapp in multiple browsers and devices. I now try to use it with angular2 and started with the ng2-sample-app tour-of-heroes with the addition of using the anuglar-cli favored webpack as module loader. You can find the code with my changes [on github](https://github.com/LarsKumbier/tour-of-heroes-webpack).

Since webpack already handles watching and live-reloading of the app, I'm primarily interested in the syhcronized scrolling, clicking, inputting, etc.

I can run browser-sync easily via the proxy-mode while running `ng serve`:

```
browser-sync start --proxy 127.0.0.1:4200
```

Afterwards, I can access `localhost:3000` and see, that browser-sync successfully injected its javascript and I can use things like syncronized scrolling, synchronized filling of input-fields (the [heroes search](https://github.com/LarsKumbier/tour-of-heroes-webpack/blob/master/src/app/hero-search/hero-search.component.html) field) and synchronized selection of things (`(click)="OnSelect()"`-Event in the [hero.component](https://github.com/LarsKumbier/tour-of-heroes-webpack/blob/master/src/app/heroes/heroes.component.html)).

However, no routing-links (e.g. `[routerLink]` in the [dashboard-component](https://github.com/LarsKumbier/tour-of-heroes-webpack/blob/master/src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html)) or buttons (e.g. the `(click)="gotoDetail()"` in the [hero.component](https://github.com/LarsKumbier/tour-of-heroes-webpack/blob/master/src/app/heroes/heroes.component.html)) are synchronized between different browsers.

Is there any way of achieving a better integration or is angular2 simply breaking the event-listener-chains through the integration of zones.js?

---

*Note:* I'm aware of the disapproval of having source-code external, but since this problem exists with *any* ng2-app, I leave it out here for readibility-reasons.